# Is there Windows DLL for PDO_IBM driver available for PHP 5.6?

Tags: db2, php, windows, db2-luw

On [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_IBM), there is the latest Windows DLL in version 1.3.3. Unfortunately, they didn't provide one for version 1.3.4. I'd like to get the DLL from some reputable source. Otherwise I'll have to compile it from sources myself in which case some hint as to what should be taken care of would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by using non-object-oriented extension ibm_db2. Fortunately, our code wasn't using many calls or special features so we were able to refactor our code quite quickly, e.g. from:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

to:

```
$stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);
```